# App installation fails in Android 12 devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions, targetsdkversion

Our app fails to install after migrating to the targetSdkVersion 31. On trying to find the issue we found that a library was using FLASHLIGHT permission and we were getting this error while installing:

> Installation failed due to: 'Failed to commit install session
> 130765275 with command cmd package install-commit 130765275. Error:
> -127: Package com.xxxx.yyyy.zzzz attempting to declare permission android.permission.FLASHLIGHT in non-existing group
> android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS'

Permissions used in the manifest file of library:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

Is there any workaround to this issue?

Comment: Can you show the Manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS is deprecated in targetSdkVersion 31 . The work around is to remove the permission used by library in your manifest by

```
<permission
      android:name="permissionOne"
      tools:node="remove"
      tools:selector="com.example.lib1">
```

> tools:node="remove"

will remove the permission from the App if its used in any of your libraries

Comment: can you be a bit more specific on what needs to be replaced according to the project  in the above code. This did not fix anything for me. I am getting the same issue for a different permission:
com.xxx.xxx.xx.andpermission.bridge

But it only worked for me after I removed the last line: tools:selector="com.example.lib1" and replaced the first line with the actual permission problem i.e. com.xxx.xxx.xx.andpermission.bridge

Comment: In place of tools:selector="com.example.lib1"  replace <com.example.lib1> with the package name of library which uses the unwanted permission...

Comment: Is there any way we can find out which library is using this permission? I am using about dozens of library.

Comment: I think need to check each library source code in GitHub if its open source.

Comment: After doing this, flashlight stopped working. How to make it work again?